# Transition matrix between bases of a polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Im stuck on how to find a transition matrix for the change of basis between two polynomial bases.

lets say that the bases are A={3, x} and B={x, 4+x}.

I understand a method for finding the transition matrix when the elements of the bases are themselves actual vectors. I can just set up an augmented matrix and use row reduction of the new basis vectors to get the result.

I'm assuming in this case I have to think in more algebraic terms, and Ive read the textbook about 15 times now but its just not making any sense. If someone can explain how to solve this Id be very grateful.

Comment: It helps to first understand more generally how to construct the matrix representation of a linear transformation with respect to two ordered bases (one for the domain and one for the target space.) During this process the abstract vectors (in this case polynomials of degree $\leq 1$) get represented by coordinates that look like vectors in the more familiar $\mathbb{R}^n$ spaces. The number of coordinates is determined by the dimension, in this case 2. Thus your polynomials will look like vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and you will end up constructing a $2\times 2$ matrix as the transition matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the elements of one basis in the other one. For example, 
$$
3=-\frac34\,x+\frac34\,(4+x),\ \ \ x=1\,x + 0\, (4-x).
$$
The transition matrix is then
$$
\begin{bmatrix} -\frac34&1\\\frac34&0\end{bmatrix}
$$